# 18.10 - Screen doesn't turn back on after Power Save Blank Screen

Tags: power-management, 18.10, amd-graphics, amd-processor, amdgpu

I have my timer set on 5 minutes. When it turns off the display, (my) user input does not wake it.

The strange thing is my monitor will turn on, but the screen will stay black. A friend of mine used AnyDesk to remotely control it, and we confirmed my input is working. I entered my password and logged in while the screen was black and while he was still connected via AnyDesk and he was still able to move my mouse around and capture this log file.

My specs:

```
AMD® Ryzen 7 1700x eight-core processor × 16
Radeon RX Vega 64 (VEGA10, DRM 3.26.0, 4.18.0-17-generic, LLVM 7.0.0)
Motherboard is a MSI x370 Pro Carbon Gaming
```

Also, I wasn't able to install the official Vega 64 drivers. After a reboot, they black screen me and I have to use TimeShift to get back and running.

Here is the log:

```
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu gnome-shell[2511]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'child->priv->parent != NULL' failed
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu gnome-shell[2511]: Extension "MinimizedWindowsList@b3e.net" had error: TypeError: global.screen is undefined
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855417] [drm:generic_reg_wait [amdgpu]] *ERROR* REG_WAIT timeout 10us * 3500 tries - dce_mi_free_dmif line:636
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855499] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 2273 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dc_helper.c:254 generic_reg_wait+0xe4/0x160 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855500] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi edac_mce_amd mt7662u_sta(OE) snd_seq kvm_amd snd_seq_device snd_timer kvm cfg80211 irqbypass wmi_bmof k10temp snd input_leds joydev soundcore ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear system76_io(OE) hid_generic usbhid hid amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 amdgpu chash gpu_sched ttm crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel syscopyarea pcbc sysfillrect sysimgblt mxm_wmi fb_sys_fops drm aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855534]  cryptd glue_helper nvme igb i2c_piix4 nvme_core ahci dca i2c_algo_bit libahci gpio_amdpt wmi gpio_generic
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855543] CPU: 10 PID: 2273 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W  OE     4.18.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855544] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7A32/X370 GAMING PRO CARBON (MS-7A32), BIOS 1.L0 01/21/2019
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855597] RIP: 0010:generic_reg_wait+0xe4/0x160 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855598] Code: a9 44 8b 45 20 48 8b 4d 18 89 de 44 89 4d d4 8b 55 10 48 c7 c7 10 24 89 c0 e8 58 67 e1 ff 41 83 7c 24 20 01 44 8b 4d d4 74 02 <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 18 44 89 c8 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 41 0f 
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855621] RSP: 0018:ffffb89803f6b7f0 EFLAGS: 00010297
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855622] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000000000000000a RCX: 0000000000000000
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855623] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9ab5dee964b8 RDI: ffff9ab5dee964b8
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855624] RBP: ffffb89803f6b830 R08: 00000000000d0d79 R09: 0000000000000002
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855625] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: ffffffff9978880d R12: ffff9ab5bfe58d00
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855626] R13: 0000000000000dad R14: 0000000000000010 R15: 0000000000000001
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855627] FS:  00007f3c11ae0a80(0000) GS:ffff9ab5dee80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855628] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855629] CR2: 00005570d446d2b0 CR3: 0000000401cdc000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855630] Call Trace:
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855692]  dce_mi_free_dmif+0xfb/0x190 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855748]  dce110_reset_hw_ctx_wrap+0x151/0x1e0 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855803]  dce110_apply_ctx_to_hw+0x52/0xa30 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855847]  ? amdgpu_pm_compute_clocks+0x17/0x20 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855902]  ? pplib_apply_display_requirements+0x1c3/0x1d0 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.855957]  ? dce110_set_bandwidth+0x1d2/0x200 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856011]  dc_commit_state+0x306/0x5b0 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856063]  ? dc_stream_get_vblank_counter+0x57/0x60 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856076]  ? drm_calc_timestamping_constants+0x109/0x150 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856134]  ? dal_irq_service_set_generic+0x5b/0x70 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856192]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x395/0xe80 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856196]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856198]  ? wait_for_completion_timeout+0x38/0x140
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856200]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856202]  ? wait_for_completion_interruptible+0x35/0x1a0
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856210]  commit_tail+0x42/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856217]  drm_atomic_helper_commit+0x113/0x120 [drm_kms_helper]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856275]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit+0x8d/0xa0 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856289]  drm_atomic_commit+0x4a/0x50 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856303]  drm_atomic_connector_commit_dpms+0xe0/0x100 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856315]  drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x187/0x2b0 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856329]  ? drm_mode_connector_set_obj_prop+0x90/0x90 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856342]  drm_mode_connector_property_set_ioctl+0x3b/0x60 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856353]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xa4/0xf0 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856364]  drm_ioctl+0x227/0x400 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856377]  ? drm_mode_connector_set_obj_prop+0x90/0x90 [drm]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856381]  ? ep_modify+0x160/0x160
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856422]  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x4f/0x90 [amdgpu]
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856425]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x620
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856429]  ? __sys_recvmsg+0x88/0xa0
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856431]  ksys_ioctl+0x67/0x90
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856433]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856436]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x110
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856438]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856439] RIP: 0033:0x7f3c12e173c7
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856440] Code: 00 00 90 48 8b 05 c9 3a 0d 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 99 3a 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856462] RSP: 002b:00007fff3432d9e8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856464] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000003 RCX: 00007f3c12e173c7
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856464] RDX: 00007fff3432da20 RSI: 00000000c01064ab RDI: 000000000000000d
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856465] RBP: 00007fff3432da20 R08: 00007fff3432d9c0 R09: 00007fff3432d9bc
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856466] R10: 002fd0ff3e8ab668 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c01064ab
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856467] R13: 000000000000000d R14: 000055e6875029c0 R15: 0000000000000000
Apr 14 15:56:42 ubuntu kernel: [  381.856469] ---[ end trace 11fd32ca95ff5c91 ]---
```

Comment: there are a few answers here one might work for you. [Ubuntu 18.04 won't wake after screen lock and blank / suspend / sleep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep)